# Find the upper bounds for the real roots of the equation $2x^3-5x^2-7x+4 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Problem:** Find the upper bounds for the real roots of the equation $2x^3-5x^2-7x+4 = 0$

Reading the definition in the book, If upon dividing f(x) by (x-r), r is an upper bound if it is greater than or equal to 0 and the coefficients of the quotients of the quotient as well as the remainder are positive.

**Trial:** The question gave an equation but no given (x-r) or r. What I did is get the roots of the cubic equation.

Root 1 = 3.36374665

Root 2 = 0.4519194497

Root 3 = -1.3256661

It says that for r to be upper bound, first it should be greater than zero, so I ignored the root -1.32

@root 1; f(r) = $2(3.36374665)^3-5(3.36374665)^2-7(3.36374665)+4 = 1.0014 x 10^-9$

And with that I know what I'm doing is wrong so I stopped. So, how to answer these kinds of problem? By the way, the choices are : 4,2,3 and 5.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that the exact wording of the problem  in the book???

Comment: The Rule of Bounds tells you if you divide the polynomial by k (k>0) by using synthetic division and the numbers of the las row are zero or positive, then it is a upper bound. The upper bound does not have to be the least upper bound. It says all real roots should be less than or equal to k.

Comment: "By the way, the choices are : 4,2,3 and 5."  Oh!  It's multple choice.  The $4$ and $5$ (and all real numbers higher) are upper bounds and 2 and 3 are not.

Comment: @fleablood Based on looking at the choices, how did you know 4 and 5 (and all real numbers higher are upper bounds) and 2 and 3 are not?

Comment: By doing the test! !Exactly! as *you* said to.  Dividing by $x-4$ gives us a polynomial with positive coefficients and a positive remainder.  SO it is an upper bound.  As $4$ is an upper bound everything greater than 4 is also an upper bound so $5$ is.  Then do the test on $3$ by dividing by $x-3$.  Then yields a negative coefficient and a negative remainder.  So $3$  and $2 < 3$ are not upper bounds.

Comment: Actually you said the largest root was $3.36374665$ so anything equal to $3.36374665$ or bigger is an upper bound and anything smaller is not.

Comment: "It says that for r to be upper bound, first it should be greater than zero,"  That is not true.  If the largest root is negative than there will be negative upper bounds.  It's not $r > 0$ but $f(r) > 0$.  (assuming the polynomials leading coefficient is positive.)

Comment: I thought you acquired the answer just by looking at the given problem and choices, my bad. From my book, "r" is an upper bound  if r ≥ 0 & that all coefficients of the quotient and the remainder are positive white "r" is a lower bound if r ≤ 0 and that the coefficients of the quotient and the remainder have alternating signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 is a upper bound.
By rational root theorem, the possible zeros are $\frac{4}{1},-\frac{4}{1},\frac{4}{2}, -\frac{4}{2}$ or $4, -4, 2, -2$

By the rules of bounds, you divide the polynomial by $4$, $(x-4)$, by using synthetic division, and the numbers of the last row are all positive or zero. Therefore, $4$ is a upper bound.

Comment: How does knowing that no  rational root is greater than 4 tell you that no root is greater than 4?

Comment: @Leo Didn't know of such theorem. But following that, 1 and -1 are also possible zeros but since they yield negative values in synthetic division, they are not upper bounds. The question says find the upper "bounds", so I thought it is asking how many upper bound values (r) does the given equation have?

Comment: @Jayce If you divide the polynomial by 5 or 6 or bigger numbers by synthetic division, the numbers of their last rows will all be positive, which means there are infinitely many upper bounds. In such case, maybe the "least upper bound" would make more sense.

Comment: Well any polynomial will have infinitely many upper bounds. ANd the least upper bound will *be* the root.  So I'm not sure what they are asking.  Maybe the least integer upper bound... but then... why?  who cares?

Comment: @Leo. Last inquiry. +4 results to a positive quotient and remainder which are the requirements for it to be an upper bound BUT the rational zero theorem states that when the root is plugged in the equation, the answer must be 0, hence the "rational zero theorem". The thing is, plugging in 4 to x does not equal to zero, not satisfying the equation: 2x3−5x2−7x+4 = 0. Err. so are we wrong? Or remainder theorem is not related to this sort of question?

Comment: "The thing is, plugging in 4 to x does not equal to zero, not satisfying the equation: 2x3−5x2−7x+4 = 0. Err. so are we wrong?"  No! the rational root test tells you what *could* be roots.  Not what *will* be roots.

Comment: @Jayce as fleablood said, it is fine to plug in 4. Our goal is to find a upper bound. I chose 4 because it is the largest possible rational root, which might be the least integer upper bound.

Comment: @Jayce You can find that 4 is exactly the least integer upper bound if you check its graph. You may use some online free graphing tool to find the graph of the polynomial.

Comment: @Jayce If you read Ross Millikan's answer below, you may now understand what he means by "the greatest to infinity" (infinitely many upper bounds).

Comment: If you need to find *one* upper bound you can just plug in any large number.  It's "clearly obvious" that $r = 100$ will be an upper bound.  So go with that.  .... But I'm pretty sure this was a multiple choice or a "horseshoes" question that you are suppose to find one closer to the root.  Leo's reasoning makes for a good guess.

Comment: To summarize, rational root theorem tells us all the possible roots of a polynomial equation and not its exact roots. There can be infinitely many upper and lower bounds for a given polynomial and when x is an upper bound, then values greater than it are all upper bounds and values below it are lower bounds. The value before a number become a lower bound is called "least upper bound". Thank you guys, I learned new things today. I hope I can be as good as you in math.

Answer (score 1):

"The question gave an equation but no given (x-r) or r"

And then:

"By the way, the choices are : 4,2,3 and 5"

You just contradicted yourself.  You are supposed to try $r = 4,2,3,5$.

==

$\frac {2x^3-5x^2-7x+4}{x-4} = 2x^2 +3x + 5 + \frac {15}{x-r}$.  The coefficient and the remainder are positive so $4$ is an upper bound.

$5 > 4$ so $5$ is also an upper bound. (Anything larger than an upper bound is an upper bound.)

$\frac {2x^3-5x^2-7x+4}{x-3} = 2x^2 + x - 5 -\frac 5{x-3}$ Stop!  A negative coefficient and a negative remainder.  $3$ is not an upper bound.

And so $2 < 3$ is not an upper bound.

So $4,5$ are upper bounds and $2$ and $3$ are not.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the values on the choices signifies quantity (4/2/3/5 upper bounds / values). The question has only 1 correct answer, but in our case the upper bounds are 4 & 5. So what is the "most" correct answer? The 4 because it is the boundary between the upper and lower or the 5 because it is the highest upper bound value on the choices?

Comment: Well, the question said upper bound***S***.  So *of the choices* $4$ and $5$ two of the infinitely many upper bounds.  "So what is the "most" correct answer?" That's an utterly meaningless question in this context. "The 4 because it is the boundary between the upper and lower or the 5 because it is the highest upper bound value on the choices?" Niether of those are interesting, important or relevant.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $2x^2-5x-7 > 0$ for $x > 4$.

Answer (score -1):

Check you definition of an upper bound.  An upper bound of a set of reals is any number greater than or equal to all members of the set.  When the set is finite the set of upper bounds is all values from the greatest to $\infty$.